# How to access the updated value in my store immediately after updating it?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have a React application that is currently using Redux for state management.

What I am trying to achieve: Click a Buy Now button - dispatch a action that makes a request to the server to add the item (increment the cart item count based on server response), check the state to see if the cart item count is greater than 0 & do something if it is.

For some reason, I have to click the button twice in order for the cartItemCount to reflect 1?

My current implementation looks like the below (I have tried to pull out all the unrelated code due to the file being quite large):

CourseSpecificScreen.tsx

```
            const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState) => {
            return {
                courseSpecificReducer: state.courseSpecificReducer,
                authState: state.authReducer,
                currencyState: state.currencyReducer,
                cartReducer: state.cartReducer,
                courseCategoriesState: state.courseCategoriesReducer,
            };
        };
        
        const mapDispatchTopProps = (dispatch: Dispatch<AnyAction>) => {
            return bindActionCreators(ActionCreators, dispatch);
        };
        
        const connector = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchTopProps);
    
    type CourseSpecificScreenNavigationProp = CompositeNavigationProp<
        StackNavigationProp<ExploreRouteStackParamList, "CourseSpecificScreen">,
        CompositeNavigationProp<
            StackNavigationProp<AppRouteHeaderParamList>,
            StackNavigationProp<AuthRouteStackParamList>
        >
    >;
    type CourseSpecificScreenRouteProp = RouteProp<
        ExploreRouteStackParamList,
        "CourseSpecificScreen"
    >;
    
    type Props = PropsFromRedux & {
        navigation: CourseSpecificScreenNavigationProp;
        route: CourseSpecificScreenRouteProp;
    };
    
    type State = {
        cartItemCount: number;
    };
    
    class CourseSpecificScreen extends Component<Props, State> {
    
    
        pruchaseItem = async () => {
            const {
                courseSpecificReducer,
                clearCartAndAddItem,
                navigation,
                cartReducer,
                getCartItemCount,
            } = this.props;
    
            const paymentMethod = paymentMethodForDevice();
    
            await clearCartAndAddItem(  
                paymentMethod, 
                courseSpecificReducer.productData.code as string,
                1,
                navigation
            )
            
            if(cartReducer.cartItemCount > 0) {
             // do some stuff
            }
        };

render() {

        return (

            <Button
                                    btnStyle={[this.getStyles().smallButtonBuyCourse]}
                                    labelStyle={[this.getStyles().buttonStickyLabelStyle]}
                                    label={translate(
                                        productData.isBundle && productData.isBundle === true
                                            ? "CategorySpecificScreen_buyThisBundle"
                                            : "CategorySpecificScreen_buyThisCourse",
                                    )}
                                    onPress={this.purchaseItem}
                                    disabled={false}
                                />
)
    };

CourseSpecificScreen.contextType = LocalizationContext;
export default connector(CourseSpecificScreen);
```

ThunkActions.ts

```
export const clearCartAndAddItem = (
    paymentMethod: string,
    productCode: string,
    quantity: number,
    navigation: any,
): AppThunk => {
    return async (dispatch) => {

        dispatch(cartActions.updateCartLoadingStatus(true));

        const response = await cartServices.clearCart();

        const {httpStatusCode} = response as APIResponse;
        
        switch (httpStatusCode) {
            case httpStatusCodes.SUCCESS_OK:
            case httpStatusCodes.SUCCESS_CREATED:
            case httpStatusCodes.SUCCESS_NO_CONTENT:    
                dispatch(cartActions.updateCartLoadingStatus(false));
                dispatch(cartActions.updateCartItemCount(0))
                globalConfig.setCartItemCount(0);
                dispatch(addItemToCart(paymentMethod, productCode, quantity, navigation));
                break;
            case httpStatusCodes.CLIENT_ERROR_UNAUTHORIZED:
            case httpStatusCodes.SERVER_ERROR_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR:
                dispatch(cartActions.updateCartLoadingStatus(false));
                let alertMessage = "Error, please try again later.";
                if (response?.message) alertMessage = response?.message;
                Alert.alert("Alert", alertMessage, [
                    {
                        text: "Ok",
                    },
                ]);
                break;
            default: {
                dispatch(cartActions.updateCartLoadingStatus(false));
            }
        }
    };
};

export const addItemToCart = (
    paymentMethod: string,
    productCode: string,
    quantity: number,
    navigation: any,
): AppThunk => {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(cartActions.updateCartLoadingStatus(true));

        const response = await cartServices.addItemToCart(productCode, quantity, paymentMethod);
        
        const {httpStatusCode, data, error, message} = response as APIResponse;
        
        console.log('add_item_to_cart_response:', response);
        
        switch (httpStatusCode) {
            case httpStatusCodes.SUCCESS_OK:
            case httpStatusCodes.SUCCESS_CREATED:
                dispatch(cartActions.updateCartLoadingStatus(false));
                dispatch(cartActions.updateCartItemCount(quantity));
                globalConfig.setCartItemCount(quantity);
        
                break;
            case httpStatusCodes.CLIENT_ERROR_UNAUTHORIZED:
                dispatch(cartActions.updateCartLoadingStatus(false));
                break;
            case httpStatusCodes.SERVER_ERROR_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR:
            case httpStatusCodes.CLIENT_ERROR_BAD_REQUEST:
                dispatch(cartActions.updateCartLoadingStatus(false));
                Alert.alert("Alert", (message)? message : "Error, it looks like you already have access to this course.", [
                    {
                        text: "Ok",
                    },
                ]);
                break;
            default: {
                dispatch(cartActions.updateCartLoadingStatus(false));
            }
        }
    };
};
```

Reducers.ts

```
const initialState: CartInitialState = {
    isLoading: true,
    cartToken: "",
    responseStatus: apiResponseStatuses.IDLE,
    cartItemCount: 0,
    isMessageVisible: false,
    message: "",
};

export default function cartReducer(
    state = initialState,
    action: CartActionTypes,
): CartInitialState {
    switch (action.type) {
        case UPDATE_LOADING_STATUS:
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoading: action.isLoading,
            };
        case UPDATE_CART_TOKEN:
            return {
                ...state,
                cartToken: action.cartToken,
            };
        case UPDATE_RESPONSE_STATUS:
            return {
                ...state,
                responseStatus: action.responseStatus,
            };
        case UPDATE_CART_ITEM_COUNT_TOKEN:
            return {
                ...state,
                cartItemCount: action.cartItemCount,
            };

        case CLEAR_DATA_ON_LOGOUT:
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoading: true,
                cartToken: "",
                responseStatus: apiResponseStatuses.IDLE,
                cartItemCount: 0,
                isMessageVisible: false,
                message: "",
            };

        default: {
            return state;
        }
    }
}
```

In the pruchaseItem() function of CourseSpecificScreen.tsx, I would like to dispatch a action that adds the item to the cart and immediately afterwards check if the cartItemCount has been updated & if it has, do something... This functionality works as expected, but only after clicking the Buy Now button twice.

I have ruled out the possibility of the issue being the API request failing the first time.

I have been stuck on this issue for several days now so any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if I need to include more information

Comment: Is there a reason you need to store ```cartItemCount`` in state variable and not directly fetch it from ```cartReducer.cartItemCount``` using ```connect``` ?
You have not shared the code where you render ```cartItemCount``` so it is hard to tell why the number is not updating but my guess would be you are not updating state variable correctly after redux update. Better to directly fetch it from redux and not use state variable at all

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. Inside pruchaseItem(),  I am using cartReducer.cartItemCount - is that when you mean when you say its "Better to directly fetch it from redux and not use state variable at all?". It almost feels like the state is always one step behind. Im trying to dispatch a action that updates the state in redux & then immediately fetch that updated piece of state. Hope that makes sense. Let me know if you need any more information

Comment: No I meant in your render method wherever you display the ```cartItemCount```.  I could not find the code where you fetch ```cartItemCount```

Comment: Aaaah, okay. So I dont actually need to display it in my render method. I only need to conditionally check it inside my pruchaseItem() function which is called when the button is pressed.

Comment: I see. Dispatch actions are async. This means after you dispatch an action there is no guarantee that the store will be updated by the time you execute your next line of code. In your case, you could either return  updated ```cartItemCount``` from ```clearCartAndAddItem``` or wait for componentDidUpdate lifecycle method to get updated ```cartItemCount``` and then do stuff in there. Let me know if you need a code example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I was storing a reference of the old cartReducer state before it was being updated.

I got this working by updating my purchaseItem() function to look like the below:

```
pruchaseItem = async () => {
    const {
        courseSpecificReducer,
        clearCartAndAddItem,
        navigation
    } = this.props;

    const paymentMethod = paymentMethodForDevice();

    await clearCartAndAddItem(  
        paymentMethod, 
        courseSpecificReducer.productData.code as string,
        1,
        navigation
    )

    const { cartReducer } = this.props;
    
    if(cartReducer.cartItemCount > 0) {
     // do some stuff
    }
};
```